# How to rebind "gj" for org/evil normal mode?

Tags: key-bindings, spacemacs

I want `gj` keys to execute function `org-next-visible-heading` (in evil normal mode). How should I do it in Spacemacs?

I was reading documentation and googling but I can't figure it out. What I tried already is adding these keys to different functions/key maps but nothing works. I tried to add these lines (one by one):

```
  (define-key org-mode-map "gj" 'org-next-visible-heading)
  (evil-define-key 'normal global-map  "gj" 'org-next-visible-heading)
  (define-key evil-normal-state-map "gj" 'org-next-visible-heading)
  (spacemacs/set-leader-keys-for-major-mode 'org-mode "gj" 'org-next-visible-heading)
  (spacemacs/set-leader-keys "gj" 'org-next-visible-heading)
  (define-key evil-normal-state-map "gj" 'org-next-visible-heading)
  (define-key evil-org-mode-map "gj" 'org-next-visible-heading)
```

in my `~/.spacemacs` at the end of section `dotspacemacs/user-config` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT

Looking a bit further, we find that `evil-org-mode` defines a minor-mode with the same name. And in [the documentation for evil-define-key](https://evil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keymaps.html#evil-define-key) we find that the syntax below can be used to configure key bindings for minor modes.

Alternatively you could use

```lisp
(evil-define-minor-mode-key 'normal 'evil-org-mode "gj" #'org-next-visible-heading)
```

For differences between these two evil macros, read the [Mode Specific Keybindings section](https://github.com/noctuid/evil-guide#mode-specific-keybindings) of noctuid's evil-guide.

END EDIT

It seems that Spacemacs uses the `evil-org` package for configuring the evil org-mode keybidnings. Indeed it is not so trivial to find how to configure those bindings. However, we can find the current binding using `SPC h d k` `g j` to find it is bound to `org-forward-element`.
Subsequently, using ripgrep (`SPC s f`), we can search for `org-forward-element` in the `.emacs.d/elpa` directory. Finally, we find that we can configure the binding as follows:

```lisp
(evil-define-key 'normal 'evil-org-mode "gj" #'org-next-visible-heading)
```

If you want to use it from your 'user-config' make sure to evaluate it after the function `evil-org-set-key-theme` has been evaluated. One way to achieve that is by advising it:

```lisp
  (advice-add 'evil-org-set-key-theme :after (lambda (_)
      (evil-define-key 'normal 'evil-org-mode "gj" #'org-next-visible-heading)))
```

Comment: It actually doesn't work until I manually run `SPC f e R` (`dostspacemacs/sync-configuration-layers`) every time i start emacs. Do you know why? Maybe some other package runs later (after my `dotspacemacs/user-config` function in dotfile) and rebinds my keys? How to make it work without me running sync-configuration-layers every time?

Comment: I guess you have to wrap it in a 'with-eval-after-load': `(with-eval-after-load 'org-evil
  (evil-define-key 'normal 'evil-org-mode "gj" #'org-next-visible-heading))`

Comment: if I use `with-eval-after-load` the keys don't work at all, even after reloading dotfile. Maybe I'll create new topic for this problem. Thank you very much for help.

Comment: Interesting, well I did not test it indeed, but that is usually how it works. However, it turns out `evil-org` uses some special 'mechanism' to set the keybingings. I have updated the answer with a better solution.

Comment: It works thank you very much :)